# Computation of the Residue of a Quotient

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have $\int_{|z| = 2}$ $\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^3 z}$ how would I compute the residue around $z=0$.  Can I simply use Cauchy's Integral Formula?

That is, should I simply get be able to calculate $e^z/(z-1)^3$ evaluated at $z = 0$?

Comment: What formula you think is that you wrote at the end? Cauchy's Integral Formula uses, unsurprisingly enough, an integral...

Comment: Sorry, edited as required.

Comment: If what you want is to evaluate that integral it is not enough to get the residue at $\,z=0\,$: you also need the residue at $\,z=1\,$ as both poles of the function are within the domain $\,|z|=2\,$

Comment: And then the result should be $2\pi i(\sum Res(f,zi))$, is that correct?

Comment: If by that sum you meant  the sum of the residues of the function on all the poles within the domain then yes, that's it.

Comment: Thank you, my apologizes for the notation.  In this case, just to clarify one final thought, we have a pole of order 3 and a simple pole (of order 1), is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

For $\,z\,$ close enough to zero:

$$\frac{e^z}{z(z-1)^3}=-\frac{1}{z}\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\ldots\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^3=$$

$$=-\left(\frac{1}{z}+1+\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\ldots\right)\left(1+z+z^2+z^3+\ldots\right)^3\;\;\;\;(**)$$

From the above, we choose only the summands that at the end give us the coefficient of $\,\frac{1}{z}\,$ :

$$(**)=-\left(\frac{1}{z}+1+\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\ldots\right)\left(1+3z+6z^2+10z^3+\ldots\right)=-\frac{1}{z}+\ldots$$

So your function's residue at $\,z=0\,$ is $\,-1\,$ .

Comment: I do understand that method, but I am more curious: does my method work?  I ask because I saw a solution worked out this way and it also led to the answer -1, but I wasn't sure if it was directly related to the use of Cauchy's Formula.

Comment: I don't think your method works, though I'm not quite sure I understand what your question is or what you're trying to prove. To evaluate integrals we need residues and not the other way around, **although** if you're given the integral's value you can reverse the argument and get the residue, at least in some cases. You either use power series or evaluate the residue using limits and derivatives. I can't understand you don't understand what I did since you must have studied power series in order to understand poles , residues and stuff...didn't you?

Comment: What I am trying to do is compute the integrals value by getting the residues and adding them up to obtain the value of the integral.  I am curious though, for the pole at 0, if my calculation is correct.  It seems to be as you obtained -1 as well.

Comment: That's good though I still don't know how you did it...:)

Comment: @user73041, I think it's about time you open a new thread or they're going to kick us out of here...:) . Anyway, I think that what you did is just calculating the integral around a little circle around the zero pole, and then yes: you can do what I believe you did, though that is **not** the value of the integral you wrote in your post.

Comment: I have edited the post - my main point of interest is why plugging in at 0 there yields the correct result.